# ngDialog scope in controller as scenario

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

i have media List , when i click at an item i want to open ngDialog and pass model to ngDialog , i have read documentation and blog but all of them use $scope to pass model or data  , not controller as (vm) . how can i use vm to pass data to ngDialog controller and how can i call parent vm($parent.$scope) from ngDiloag controller in vm(Controller as) case

here is my code (simplified version )

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app.media')
        .controller('mediaController', Controller);

    Controller.$inject = ['$filter', 'ngTableParams', '$rootScope', '$http', '$log', '$uibModal', 'ngDialog', 'toaster', 'mediaDataService'];

    function Controller($filter, ngTableParams, $rootScope, $http, $log, $uibModal, ngDialog, toaster, mediaDataService) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.media = {};


        activate();



        function activate() {

            vm.updateMedia = function () {
                mediaDataService.updateMedia(vm.media).then(function (res) {
                    toaster.pop('success', 'ویرایش فایل با موفقیت انجام شد', 'ویرایش فایل')
                })
            }


            vm.openUpdateDialog = function (media) {
                //i want to use vm.media in opening dialog
                vm.media = media;
                ngDialog.open({
                    template: 'media/edit'
                    , className: 'ngdialog-theme-default'
                    , controller: 'updateMediaController',

                    //i had used data to pass data to new controller and used ngDialogData in my opening template to access media , 
                    //the probelm with this case is i cant access parrent controller(the controller that is openin dialog) from DngDialog
                    //opened Controller(because i want to run parrent controller  updateMedia function  when user click update in opened dialog)
                    //**commented out - not usefull **//    
                    //data:media
                })
            }

        }
    }
})();
```

any suggestion ?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

> If you use a controller with separate $scope service this object will be passed to the $scope.$parent param:
>    [see this for more  information](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog)

```
 ngDialog.open({
                template: 'media/edit',
                 className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
                 controller: 'updateMediaController',
                 scope:$scope
            })
```

Comment: i am not using $scope in my parrent controller.

Comment: try this controllerAs: 'vm or other'

Comment: thanks a lot , it solved the problem , however i didnt want to inject $scope in my controller , but it seems there is no way to achive what i wanted  without using $scope.thanks alot